# WordPress Thickbox Navigation Issue in Gallery

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, jquery-ui, thickbox

I am adding an image gallery via wp media uploader. In the frontend, I am trying to show these images in Thickbox pop-up. However, it shows the images in pop-up but when I navigate [next and prev images] it suddenly works and an error is seen in the console.

This is the error:
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/IMG_0139.jpg&width=753&height=470?random=1555568706302 404 (Not Found). If I paste this url, 404 page is seen.

All in all, the navigation buttons are not working properly. If I add 2 images in gallery, the next button box works but prev button throws error. If I use more than 2 images, the next disappears after second images and prev button fails as well.

This is my code for front-end where images are displayed:

```
<?php
foreach ($ids as $key => $value):
    $image_medium = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value, 'medium');
    $image_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value, 'full');
    $attachment_title = get_the_title($value);
?>
    <li>
        <a rel="gallery" href="<?php echo esc_url($image_full[0]); ?>">
        <img class="guide-gallery-image" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($attachment_title); ?>" src="<?php echo esc_url($image_medium[0]); ?>" />
        </a>
    </li> 
<?php
endforeach; ?>
```

This is how I have added `thickbox()` resources (css and js) in my footer:

```
<?php
add_thickbox();
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: That URL is obviously invalid (query string starts with the `?` simbol). But your code works fine for me, except there should be a `class="thickbox"` in the `<a>` tag...

Comment: @SallyCJ That url is auto generated from the `thickbox()`. Is the navigation working?

Comment: Yes, it is working properly. Why didn't you add the `thickbox` to the link (`a`) `class`? Do you have a custom script which setups Thickbox on the links?

Comment: I tried that as well but no help. You can check it the issue in these 2 links: http://prntscr.com/ne039y
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u2rit3xHftHYw-47ruMK0iMrmOnRlpjH

Next button does not appear after 2nd image if there are more than 2 images. Further, Prev button fails as well.

Comment: Ok, but you haven't answered my other question - is there a script which automatically setups Thickbox on the links? Because to me, it seems there is. Try disabling all plugins and/or try a default theme.

Comment: My mistake. There was a JS error in my code which triggered this error. Now both are fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @saurav.rox, it's good to know the issue has been solved. :)